# MongoDB apply sort on pagination result

Tags: mongodb

I want to apply pagination on my db. the page size is 500. now I want to sort records by page. like I want to sort records of the first page result only. is it possible?

```
db.getCollection('emp').find().limit(500).sort({Groupcode:1});
```

this will sort on whole db not on 500 records. i want to sort on pagination result.

Comment: If you get your solution from the given answer then kindly accept the answer.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an **aggregate** such as:

```
db.getCollection('emp').aggregate([
    {"$limit": 500},
    {"$sort": {"Groupcode": 1}}
])
```

This will first limit the records then apply sorting on limited records